# How to hide the elements using bootstrap classes?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to do do a small testing using bootstrap, where I want to show h1 only for desktop /large and h2 only for mobile but when I use the following , both h1 and h2 show-up on all screens .

h1 and h2 is input element and writing condition depending on whether they are filled or not.

```
if(h1 != null){
<h1 class="d-none d-lg-block d-xl-none"> Test 1</h1>
}
else{
<h2 class = "d-block d-sm-none"> Test 2 </h2>
}
```

Comment: add the classes without the dot, for example d-none and not .d-none

Comment: Class names in the `class` attribute need to be written without the leading dot, that is part of CSS selector syntax only.

Comment: sorry , when i copied the class forgot to remove

Comment: @CBroe question is still the same , when i tried to copy the class to here to ask question , forgot to remove dots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for the conditional statement, Bootstraps [display properties](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/) should work fine for you.

You only need the `.` if you are specifying the class outside the markup in CSS or JS for example.

You can use `d-xl-block` on `h1` for it show over `1140px` (desktop). Then just use `d-xl-none` on the `h2'`s since you don't want them to be present when `h1` is showing.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">

<h1 class="d-none d-xl-block">Test 1</h1>

<h2 class="d-block d-xl-none">Test 2</h2>
```